# APC module causing strange error

Tags: linux, php, centos6, pecl, alternative-php-cache

When I run 
`php -v`

I get:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/apc.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/apc.so: undefined symbol: php_pcre_exec in Unknown on line 0

This isn't my first rodeo.  I've setup APC multiple times.  This is a MediaTemple Dedicated Virtual 4.0 with Plesk 11.  Plesk 11 is the only thing essentially different from the other servers I've set this up on.

I've verified that `pcre-devel` is installed.  I've compiled APC from source as well as used pecl to install it. No difference.

I also tried downgrading to APC 3.0.19, with no love.

Comment: Why not just use the packages provided by the distribution (and you forgot to mention which you're using)?

Comment: It's CentSO 6. If there are any yum packages for this, I haven't seen them.

Comment: `php-pecl-apc` has been in the repos for quite some time.

Comment: For whatever, reason, it's not in my repos. "No package php-pecl-apc available." (please let me know if I'm missing something obvious...not an expert on this stuff)

Comment: I suspect Plesk. But you'd have to ask MT to be sure.

Comment: `cat /etc/php.d/apc.ini`?

Comment: It has extension=apc.so.  The issue is that the module fails to load.

Answer (score 0):

First install the pecl package from yum repo and then use the below command to install the apc.

```
pecl install apc
```

that's it.

Comment: Yes, I used that method. As I said above "I've compiled APC from source as well as used pecl to install it. No difference."